# Easy way to parse multi-node msbuild output to single nodes?

Tags: msbuild, customization

I have a solution of hundred plus VC++ projects. When I build using VS 2010 or via command line, the output shows several hundreds of nodes spitting output simultaneously.

For example:

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: abc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ami, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: pqr, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>  stdafx.cpp
1>  stdafx.cpp
2>  stdafx.cpp
3>  ViewTree.cpp
1>  ViewTree.cpp
3>  PropertiesWnd.cpp
2>  ViewTree.cpp
1>  PropertiesWnd.cpp
2>  PropertiesWnd.cpp
3>  pqrView.cpp
1>  OutputWnd.cpp
3>  pqrDoc.cpp
2>  OutputWnd.cpp
1>  MainFrm.cpp
3>  pqr.cpp
1>  FileView.cpp
2>  MainFrm.cpp
3>  OutputWnd.cpp
3>  MainFrm.cpp
1>  ClassView.cpp
2>  FileView.cpp
3>  FileView.cpp
1>  ChildFrm.cpp
2>  ClassView.cpp
3>  ClassView.cpp
1>  abcView.cpp
2>  ChildFrm.cpp
1>  abcDoc.cpp
3>  ChildFrm.cpp
2>  amiView.cpp
1>  abc.cpp
3>  Generating Code...
2>  amiDoc.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
2>  ami.cpp
2>  Generating Code...
1>  abc.vcxproj -> c:\temp\ami\Debug\abc.exe
2>  ami.vcxproj -> c:\temp\ami\Debug\ami.exe
3>  pqr.vcxproj -> c:\temp\ami\Debug\pqr.exe
========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Question is how do make (parse this output into nodes grouped by their number.

For example:

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: abc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  ViewTree.cpp
1>  PropertiesWnd.cpp
1>  OutputWnd.cpp
1>  MainFrm.cpp
1>  FileView.cpp
1>  ClassView.cpp
1>  ChildFrm.cpp
1>  abcView.cpp
1>  abcDoc.cpp
1>  abc.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  abc.vcxproj -> c:\temp\ami\Debug\abc.exe

2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ami, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  stdafx.cpp
2>  ViewTree.cpp
2>  PropertiesWnd.cpp
2>  OutputWnd.cpp
2>  MainFrm.cpp
2>  FileView.cpp
2>  ClassView.cpp
2>  ChildFrm.cpp
2>  amiView.cpp
2>  amiDoc.cpp
2>  ami.cpp
2>  Generating Code...
2>  ami.vcxproj -> c:\temp\ami\Debug\ami.exe

3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: pqr, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>  stdafx.cpp
3>  ViewTree.cpp
3>  PropertiesWnd.cpp
3>  pqrView.cpp
3>  pqrDoc.cpp
3>  pqr.cpp
3>  OutputWnd.cpp
3>  MainFrm.cpp
3>  FileView.cpp
3>  ClassView.cpp
3>  ChildFrm.cpp
3>  Generating Code...
3>  pqr.vcxproj -> c:\temp\ami\Debug\pqr.exe

========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

This is needed so that I can look at exact failing project and it's failing cpp files. I also need the summary like failed projects: abc, xyz...

Is there a quick way to achieve this rather than write a $300 addin?

Comment: Learn how to format questions, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but in Visual Studio in Output window you can select 'Show output from: Build Order'. By default it is selected to 'Show output from:Build' which is not ordered.

Comment: Yes this was exactly what I needed from the IDE. No idea how to make output appear in 'build order' when build is invoked from command line msbuild foo.sln ...

Comment: Do you want to see ordered build in Visual Studio when running build using Tools | External Tools (like in this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

VSCommands free edition does a lot of this.

Or switch off/set degree of parallelism to 1 in tools|options|projects&solutions

Or parse the file logs with Powershell and trigger it in a Post build step or MSBuild target.